# How to make Custom Rule set in Graphdb

Tags: rule-engine, graphdb

I am trying to make customs rules in Graphdb. I have a **Person** ontology which has classes "Parent" and "Child", and object property "hasChild" and "hasGrandChild".
There are three nodes with relationship like this:
:Ali :hasChild :Aslam
:Aslam :hasChild :Ahmed

Now I want to infer that ":Ali :hasGrandChild :Ahmed" in Graphdb. Builtin ruleset like owl horst optimized does not work.
I tried using .pie file for making custom rules but new rules are not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/reasoning.html#custom-rulesets ?

Answer (score 2):

GraphDB gives you the flexibility to develop your own rules if you want to express semantics not part of the OWL or RDFS standards. In this example, you try to define that the property `hasGranChild` is a chain of two `hasChild` properties. This is possible with OWL property chain axiom.

My suggestion is to use the standard OWL semantics part of OWL 2 RL and OWL 2 QL rulesets in GraphDB. Here is an example:

```
@prefix :      <http://www.example.org/> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:hasParent  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

:hasGrandChild  owl:propertyChainAxiom
                ( :hasChild :hasChild ) .

:Ahmed :hasChild :Ali .
:Ali :hasParent :Aslam .
```

Please do not forget to change the default ruleset to OWL 2 RL or OWL 2 QL during the repository creation.

Answer (score 1):

I created a ruleset file called “CustomRule.pie”. It has three main parts “Prefices”, “Axioms”, and “Rules”.
 
In Prefices, I inserted our ontology Prefix like:
Person   :http://www.semanticweb.org/hamza/ontologies/2017/6/Person.owl#
Then in Axioms, we have to write all the triples Subject, Predicate, Object that we have inserted in our ontology. Like:
<'Person:Ahmed'> <'Person:hasChild'> <'Person:Ali'>
<'Person:Ali'> <'Person:hasChild'> <'Person:Aslam'> 
//Ingore commas 
 
Finally, in Rules section, we can write entailment rules. It checks all the axioms available in the Axioms section to implement rules. Like 
Id: custom
      a <'Person:hasChild'> b
      b <'Person:hasChild'> c
    ------------------------------------
      a <'Person:hasGrandChild'> c